# Make a time series plot of NDWI based water area extraction

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, normalized-difference-water-index

I want to make a time series of NDWI based extraction of water pixels using Google Earth Engine. I can successfully make the mask but I am not able to code it properly to store the values of water area in a collection and plot the time series.

```
var areaOfInterest =
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[16.278247539412213, 59.84820707394825],
          [16.363563243757916, 59.84820707394825],
          [16.363563243757916, 59.88922451187625],
          [16.278247539412213, 59.88922451187625]]]);

// Zoom to area of interest
Map.centerObject(areaOfInterest);
Map.addLayer(areaOfInterest);


// Load Sentinel-2 data

var startDate = '2015-07-01';
var endDate = '2018-07-31';

// Returns all the images between the start date and the end date
// taken on the area of interest
var sentinelImageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterBounds(areaOfInterest)
                  .filterDate(startDate, endDate);

print("Number of images = ", sentinelImageCollection.size());

// We select the image with the smallest cloudy pixel percentage
var sentinelImage = sentinelImageCollection.sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
    .first()
    .clip(areaOfInterest);

print("Sentinel image taken at = ", sentinelImage.date());

// Visualize using RGB
Map.addLayer(sentinelImage, {min: 0.0, max: 2000, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']}, 'RGB');

// Visualize using NDWI
var ndwi = sentinelImage.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI');
Map.addLayer(ndwi, {palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue']}, 'NDWI');

// Calculate the area of our region of interest
var aoiArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: areaOfInterest,
    scale: 10,
}).get('area');
print('AOI area (km2):', aoiArea);

// Create NDWI mask
var ndwiThreshold = ndwi.gte(0.0);
var ndwiMask = ndwiThreshold.updateMask(ndwiThreshold);
Map.addLayer(ndwiThreshold, {palette:['black','white']}, 'NDWI Binary Mask');
Map.addLayer(ndwiMask, {palette:['blue']}, 'NDWI Mask');

// We can now calculate the masked areas pixel area
var ndwiPixelArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(ndwiMask.select('NDWI')).divide(1e6).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group(1),
    geometry: areaOfInterest,
    scale: 10,
    bestEffort: true
});

var list = ee.List(ee.Dictionary(ndwiPixelArea).get('groups'));
var group0 = ee.Dictionary(list.get(0));
var ndwiWaterArea = ee.Number(group0.get('sum')).float();
print("Water area (km2):", ndwiWaterArea);

var waterRatio = ndwiWaterArea.divide(aoiArea);
print("Water ratio from area:", waterRatio);


// Chart the time series
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(ndwiWaterArea, 'timestamp')
  .setChartType('LineChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Surface Water Area Time Series',
    hAxis: {title: 'Time'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Water Area (m²)'}
  });

// Display the chart
print(chart);
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your code that calculates the area to a function and return an `ee.Feature` with your area and timestamp as properties. Then you map over the image collection using this function. That gives you a feature collection that you can chart.

Note that this approach of calculating the area scene by scene will cause you problems when a single scene doesn't cover the complete AOI. You might consider creating a time-series of composites and calculate the area based on that. This code also doesn't perform any cloud masking, giving you incorrect water area where you're having cloud cover. Even if you do cloud masking, the water area will be affected by masked out pixels - a time-series of the ratio of water might be more useful here? Nevertheless, this should get you started:

```
var areas = sentinelImageCollection.map(toNdwiArea)     

var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
  features: areas, 
  xProperty: 'date', 
  yProperties: ['area']
})
  .setChartType('LineChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Surface Water Area Time Series',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Water Area (m²)'
    }
  })
print(chart)  
  
  
function toNdwiArea(sentinelImage) {
  var ndwi = sentinelImage.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI')
  var ndwiMask = ndwi.gte(0.0)
  var ndwiPixelArea = ee.Image.pixelArea()
    .updateMask(ndwiMask)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: areaOfInterest,
      scale: 10,
      bestEffort: true
    })
    return ee.Feature(null, ndwiPixelArea)
      .set('date', sentinelImage.date())
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8631d80d37d1372b4ba827daf1f4ab82